# Which expressions describe $\frac{e}{2}-\frac{e^2}{4}+\frac{e^3}{6}-\frac{e^4}{8}+....$

Tags: calculus, summation, infinity

I'm taking single variable Calculus on Coursera and asked following :

> Which of the following expressions describes the sum $\frac{e}{2}-\frac{e^2}{4}+\frac{e^3}{6}-\frac{e^4}{8}+....$ :
>   $$1. \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{e^k}{2k} $$
>   $$2. \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k}\frac{e^{k+1}}{2k+2} $$
>   $$3. \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{e^{k+1}}{2k+2} $$
>   $$4. \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k}\frac{e^{k+1}}{2k+2} $$
>   $$5. \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{e^k}{2k} $$
>   $$6. \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k}\frac{e^k}{2k} $$

Question screenshot :

[image]
My solution :

$$ e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Using k = 1 for $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{e^k}{2k} $

$$(-1)^{1+1}\frac{e^1}{2} $$

=

$$1\frac{e^1}{2} $$

=

$$\frac{e^1}{2} $$

Using k = 2 for $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{e^k}{2k} $

$$(-1)^{2+1}\frac{e^2}{4} $$

=

$$-1\frac{e^2}{4} $$

=

$$-\frac{e^2}{4} $$

$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{e^k}{2k} $ matches $k=1, k=2$ the sum expression $\frac{e}{2}-\frac{e^2}{4}$ . Is the solution to keep plugging in values for k and checking which match the sum expressions ? But this does not tell me $\frac{e}{2}-\frac{e^2}{4}+\frac{e^3}{6}-\frac{e^4}{8}+....$ as it just provides an answer for first 4 k terms.

Is there a more intuitive method to solve this ?

Comment: I do not think you need to evaluate the sum, i.e. you do not need to find a closed formula for the "result". You just need to pick the option where the $k$-th term is given by the correct expression.

Comment: Is there a typo? since here 1=5=6...

Comment: There could also be a typo (missing `{ ... }`) turning some $e^{k+1}$ into $e^k+1$?

Comment: @Olivier Oloa I've updated question with screenshot, where's typo ?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I've updated question with screenshot, where's typo ?

Comment: User egreg just fixed the typos; see his edit.

Comment: There are four typos remaining ! My -1 to the OP for leaving so many of them.

Comment: @Yves Daoust typos fixed , thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $$\frac{e}{2}-\frac{e^2}{4}+\frac{e^3}{6}-\dots = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1}\frac{e^{k}}{2k}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}\frac{e^{k+1}}{2(k+1)}.$$
The idea is to simply write it using the sum notation and then do a substitution to get the correct summation.

So I would definitely answer $4$ (I guess there is a mistake in the exponents as written down in the question).

Comment: @Arthur: Whoops, fixed it, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I've updated question with screenshot, where is mistake ?

Comment: In the fourth formula, it's $e^{k+1}$ not $e^k+1$ as you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, in all the given series, the signs go alternating, the exponents increase by one and the denominators increase by two from term to term. Then if the first term is right, so will all the following ones.

- $-\dfrac10$;
- $\color{green}{+\dfrac e2}$;
- $-\dfrac e2$;
- $-\dfrac{e^2}4$;
- $\color{green}{+\dfrac e2}$;
- $-\dfrac e2$.

---

If you are interested by the value of the sum, the answer is easy: it doesn't exist, as the terms grow to infinity.